# Keep track of server synchronization state

Tags: redux

I'm creating an indicator which notifies the user about whether or not the local state is in sync with the latest fetched server state. I can think of several ways to keep track of this:

- storing an additional 'pristine' state next to the normal 'soiled' state upon fetching data and diffing those states in my indicator component
- toggling a up-to-date-flag upon state changes and fetching data back and forth

But those solutions seem over-engineered and error-prone to me. I think middleware is probably the cleanest solution here, but thusfar I haven't came across a viable out-of-the-box solution. If anyone could hook me up, because I probably lack the right idiom to use in my search terms, that would be awesome. On a sidenote: I'm not allowed to store my data in the localstorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend calculating a hash (this works as the signature of your state) of your data on the server, and sending it along with your data to local clients. Your clients can then use this hash to know if it matches with the latest data.

You might also want to take a look at `Etag` for a more standardized approach.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

Comment: Hashing, of course. Should've known. Hoped for some out-of-the-box solution, but this is acceptable as well.